# Modifying environment variable within a C program

Tags: c, variables, environment

Is it possible to modify an environment variable within a C program. Something like this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
int main( void )
{
    system( "echo $VARIABLE" );
    system( "VARIABLE=somethig");
    system( "echo $VARIABLE" );
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes. See the unix utility `env`. But not like you're trying to.

Comment: You should have [setenv](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/setenv.html) if you've included `<stdlib.h>`.

Comment: [setenv](http://linux.die.net/man/3/setenv)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setenv(const char *name, const char *value, int overwrite);` is the function you need.

e.g. `setenv("CONFIG_PATH", "/etc", 0);`

From the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/setenv):

> **DESCRIPTION**
>   The  `setenv()`  function  adds  the  variable `name` to the environment
>   with the value `value`, if `name` does not already exist.  If `name` 
>   does exist in the environment, then its value is changed to `value`
>   if overwrite is nonzero; if overwrite is zero, then the `value` 
>   of `name` is not changed.  This  function  makes copies of the strings pointed 
>   to by `name` and `value` (by contrast with `putenv(3)`).

Answer (score 8):

Use [`setenv()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/setenv.html) or
[`putenv()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/putenv.html). Beware the gotchas with `putenv()`.

Your code as written sets the environment of a new shell interpreter spawned by call to `system()`. That environment is discarded when `system()` returns.